# Status : 500 - b'Failed to find the datastore factory for gpkg, did you forget to install the store extension jar

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-api

when i am trying to publish layer using the Geoserver-rest api.

geo.publish_featurestore(workspace='demo',store_name='gpkg',pg_table='file_name')

but gettting this error

Status : 500 - b'Failed to find the datastore factory for gpkg, did you forget to install the store extension jar.

Comment: which version of GeoServer?

Comment: geoserver 2.23 @IanTurton

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @anonymous_1729 Did you manage to solve it?